# What does 'Convert the .iso file to .img ' mean?

Tags: installation

I was gong to install Ubuntu on my Mac using USB.

At the moment i'm reading instructions and I don't understand them:
[Here are the instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

It says

> Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil

Can anyone explain me what `.img` is, what it is for, and where I can get it?

Comment: Please, don't use CAPS, it looks like you are shouting as you probably know. Also consider to provide a more usefull title next time, one that describes your problem. You will find you might get more help that way!

Answer (score 2):

hdiutil is a MAC utility which you need to run in terminal to convert the Ubuntu .iso to .IMG

When you down load an Ubuntu installable from ubuntu website, the installable is a .iso extension installable. For installing it on a MAC machine, you need to run the above utility to convert the ubuntu ".iso" extensioned file to ".img" extensioned file.

So for e.g if the Ubuntu installable that you have downloaded is 'ubuntu.iso' then after running the above command, it will get converted to 'ubuntu.img'

Follow the instructions as mentioned in the url in your question.